# Why i am getting throughput exceed exception ? how to resolve it ? i am using provisioned mode 20RCU AND 20WCU

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, backend

I am using dynamodb to store my data from an IOT device, my table has one partition key (string) and one sort key timestamp in milliseconds and other columns are parameters name. I am getting 2 records every minute. Now whenever I try to fetch data I am getting throughput to exceed exception error even though I am fetching very fewer data, how to resolve it, this is only a development phase what will happen in production?
my query function is

```
export const getAllConfigData = async (
  tableName,
  process_uuid,
  startTime,
  endTime,
  parameters
) => {
  const resultData = { Items: [] };
  let result;
  const parameterNames = parameters.map((p) => p.parameterName);
  parameterNames.push("#DocTimestamp");
  const parameterNamesString = parameterNames.join(",");
  const pageSize = 100; // Fetch 100 items at a time
  let lastKey;

  do {
    const params = {
      TableName: tableName,
      KeyConditionExpression:
        "process_uuid = :id AND #DocTimestamp BETWEEN :start AND :end",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#DocTimestamp": "timestamp",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":id": process_uuid,
        ":start": startTime,
        ":end": endTime,
      },
      ProjectionExpression: parameterNamesString,
      ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL",
      Limit: pageSize,
    };

    if (lastKey) {
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = lastKey;
    }

    result = await ddbDocClient.send(new QueryCommand(params));
    console.log(result.ConsumedCapacity);
    if (result.Items) {
      resultData.Items.push(...result.Items);
    }

    lastKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
  } while (lastKey);

  return resultData;
};
```

initially, we are getting throughput to exceed exception so we change our table capacity from provisioned to on-demand this resolves my issue but capacity is used in very high 4500 RCU WCU which is too much this will increase the AWS bill. but in the on-demand case, we are getting the throttling exception error .now we make it provisioned as it was previously, is there any alternative to make my work done .

Answer (score 0):

#### Assumption

You're clearly not requesting a small amount of data if you require pagination.

#### On-demand Works

In On-demand mode you can retrieve 3000 RCU for your Query if you use strongly consistent reads, more if you are not.

#### Provisioned Mode Throttling

Each 4KB of data will cost 0.5 RCU. So depending on how much data you need to retrieve will determine the throughput that you need to provision. You currently use 20RCU, this will provide you the ability to retrieve a little more than 160KB per second. You can tell how much capacity you are consuming with the returned capacity in each response.

#### How to overcome

If you don't want to pay for the capacity you need to consume to get the work done, then I suggest you rate limit your requests. You can do this quite simply by reducing the number of items returned in each request and adding a small amount of sleep between them. You can of course use something more robust like Googles Guava if you like.

Comment: Can you suggest one database that we can use to make my work done for now as well as in the future when the project scales, this project is actually a dashboard in which we are first getting at max data of 1 month then doing some calculation manipulation on data then we are creating graph according to our requirement? we are fetching data for 1 day,1 week, 1 month sometime 6 months also, and as I said every minute we are getting 2 records in my table from the IOT device, and the size of one record is 3.23KB for now it will increase surely in future

Comment: You can get the scale you need from DynamoDB easily. You just have to increase your capacity to provide you the needed throughput.

Comment: yea but that will also increase cost ,

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can rate limit to reduce cost if you are not willing to pay for the capacity needed. There's a performances vs cost trade off which you need to consider.

Comment: yes you are right but the rate limit will increase my response time, we can not put a delay, we want to show that data after manipulation and much more calculation on the dashboard

Comment: If you need speed then you will to increase your capacity.

Comment: You could also use DynamoDB streams & Lambda to pre-aggregate your data so that you don't have to request so much, turning Queries of MBs into GetItems of KBs.